# Finding size of BST via recursion

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Trying to recursively find the size (total objects) in a linked BST. Getting weird incorrect returns, not totally sure why.

```
 private int size(BinaryTreeNode<T> root)
   {
      if (root == null) // empty tree
         return 0;
      
      if (root.getRight() == null && root.getLeft() == null) // base case, only root node exists
         return 1;
         
      else if (root.getRight() == null && root.getLeft() != null) // only left node exists
         return size(root.getLeft()) + 1;
      else if (root.getRight() != null && root.getLeft() == null) // only right node exists
         return size(root.getRight()) + 1;
      else
         return size(root.getRight()) + size(root.getLeft()) + 1; // right and left nodes exist
   }
```

When finding the size of the tree:

```
    < 33 >
 1 >     < 67 >
   12 >  1    80
      13
```

I get 1 as the return size instead of 6.

Comment: Can you share the way you have constructed your tree?

Comment: It won't likely help you debug it, but can't you remove most of that method and just use the `if(root == null)` base case, and also your implementation's final case?

Comment: Good point, should have recognized that to begin with. That consolidates a lot, thanks!

Comment: @ShashankGarg unfortunately not. This is a course project, so the class defining the way the tree is constructed is a good bit above my current abilities. The best I could do is post the entire file.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct but can be simplified to this.

```
    private int size(BinaryTreeNode<T> root)
    {
        if (root == null) // empty tree
            return 0;
        
        return 1 + size(root.getLeft()) + size(root.getRight());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private int size(BinaryTreeNode<T> root)
   {
      if (root == null) 
         return 0;
      int left = size(root.getLeft());
      int right = size(root.getright());
      return (1+left+right);
  }
```